# Filter out unwanted XML data using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following NUnit result XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="C:\Selenium\TestResults\NewVersion.xsl"?>
<!--This file represents the results of running a test suite-->
<test-results name="C:\Selenium\VisualStudio\Automated Tests\Automated Tests\AutomatedTests\bin\Debug\AutomatedTests.dll" total="2" errors="1" failures="0" not-run="0" inconclusive="0" ignored="0" skipped="0" invalid="0" date="2014-10-06" time="11:54:11">
<environment nunit-version="2.6.3.13283" clr-version="2.0.50727.5485" os-version="Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1" platform="Win32NT" cwd="C:\Selenium" machine-name="U0130917-TPL-A" user="U0130917" user-domain="TEN" />
  <culture-info current-culture="en-GB" current-uiculture="en-US" />
 <test-suite type="Assembly" name="C:\Selenium\VisualStudio\Automated Tests\Automated Tests\AutomatedTests\bin\Debug\AutomatedTests.dll" executed="True" result="Failure" success="False" time="123.997" asserts="0">
   <results>
  <test-suite type="Namespace" name="AutomatedTests" executed="True" result="Failure" success="False" time="123.971" asserts="0">
    <results>
      <test-suite type="TestFixture" name="GridClientListPageVerificationGridTest" executed="True" result="Failure" success="False" time="123.913" asserts="0">
        <categories>
          <category name="GridSpitfireTests" />
        </categories>
        <results>
          <test-case name="AutomatedTests.GridClientListPageVerificationGridTest.ClientListPageVerificationGridTest_MainTest" executed="True" result="Error" success="False" time="123.269" asserts="33">
            <failure>
              <message><![CDATA[My MESSAGE ]]></message>
              <stack-trace>
                <![CDATA[Mystack trace]]>   
</stack-trace>
                </failure>
          </test-case>
        </results>
      </test-suite>
      <test-suite type="Namespace" name="PracticeCode" executed="True" result="Failure" success="False" time="0.017" asserts="0">
        <results>
          <test-suite type="Namespace" name="Basics" executed="True" result="Failure" success="False" time="0.016" asserts="0">
            <results>
              <test-suite type="TestFixture" name="PracticeCode_ArithmaticOperators" executed="True" result="Failure" success="False" time="0.016" asserts="0">
                <results>
                  <test-case name="AutomatedTests.PracticeCode.Basics.PracticeCode_ArithmaticOperators.PracticeCode_ArithmaticOperators_Main" executed="True" result="Success" success="True" time="0.015" asserts="0">                     
                    <failure>
                      <message>
                        <![CDATA[My MESSAGE]]>
                      </message>
                      <stack-trace>
                        <![CDATA[Mystack trace ]]>
                      </stack-trace>
                    </failure>
                  </test-case>
                </results>
              </test-suite>
            </results>
          </test-suite>
        </results>
      </test-suite>
      <test-suite type="Namespace" name="PracticeCode" executed="True" result="Success" success="True" time="0.013" asserts="0">
        <results>
          <test-suite type="Namespace" name="Basics" executed="True" result="Success" success="True" time="0.013" asserts="0">
            <results>
              <test-suite type="TestFixture" name="PracticeCode_ArithmaticOperators" executed="True" result="Success" success="True" time="0.012" asserts="0">
                <results>
                  <test-case name="AutomatedTests.PracticeCode.Basics.PracticeCode_ArithmaticOperators.PracticeCode_ArithmaticOperators_Main" executed="True" result="Success" success="True" time="0.011" asserts="0" />
                </results>
              </test-suite>
            </results>
          </test-suite>
        </results>
      </test-suite>
    </results>
  </test-suite>
</results>
</test-suite>
</test-results>
```

...and have the following style sheet

```
 <xsl:template match="/">
<html>
  <body>
    <!--If failures is greater than 0, display a failure summary-->
    <xsl:if test="/test-results/@errors>0 or /test-results/@failures>0">

      <!--Header for Fail Summary-->
      <span style="font-size:medium;">
        <br/>
        <h3>Failure/Message Summary</h3>
      </span>
      <br/>

      <!--Table for Failed/Errored Test Cases-->
      <table border="2" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
        <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
          <!--Specify the headers-->
          <th style="text-align:center">Test Case Name</th>
          <th style="text-align:center">Message</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="//test-case">
          <!--Sort table by test case name-->
          <xsl:sort select="@name"/>
          <tr>
            <td style="text-align:left">
              <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:left">
              <span style="font-size:large; font-weight:bold; color:red;">
                Message =
              </span>
              <xsl:value-of select="failure/message"/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <span style="font-size:large; font-weight:bold; color:red;">
                StackTrace =
              </span>
              <xsl:value-of select="failure/stack-trace"/>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
      <br/>
    </xsl:if>
  </body>
</html>
 </xsl:template>
```

I am trying to build a table around these NUnit results were tests that have failed are included in the table, with their message and stack trace, but tests that have NOT  failed are excluded from the table.

At the moment the above style sheet builds the table, but includes all of the tests passed or failed.

I would be grateful for any assistance.  Please note, I have started learning XSL two days ago, so simple solution would be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

Found the following answer as a solution to my issue...

Wrapped the table rows in an if statement to evaluate if 'Success' was false

```
 <!--Table for Failed/Errored Test Cases-->
      <table border="2" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
        <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
          <!--Specify the headers-->
          <th style="text-align:center">Test Case Name</th>
          <th style="text-align:center">Message</th>
        </tr>
        <!--Fore each test case, if Success = false, display the test name and message/stack trace-->         
        <xsl:for-each select="//test-case">
          <xsl:sort select="@name"/>
          <xsl:if test="./@success = 'False'">
          <!--Sort table by test case name-->        
          <tr>
            <td style="text-align:left">
              <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:left">
              <span style="font-size:large; font-weight:bold; color:red;">
                Message =
              </span>
              <xsl:value-of select="failure/message"/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <span style="font-size:large; font-weight:bold; color:red;">
                StackTrace =
              </span>
              <xsl:value-of select="failure/stack-trace"/>
            </td>
          </tr>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
```